# Django auto submit form when user done typing?

Tags: django

I have a form with a text field and i want to receive user input and after user done typing (about 2s). Is there a way to achieve this in django(i only know how to do this in pure js)
Edit: i added ajax to template but it not auto submit after time out.
My model and form:

```
class ProductName(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class ProductNameForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ProductName
    fields = ('name',)
```

My template:

```
<div id="searchbar" class="d-flex flex-row">
<form action="search_result" method=POST class="my-form input-group flex-nowrap bg-light mx-0 mx-lg-auto rounded p-1">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ place.place }}
    {% render_field form.name placeholder="Search product..." class+="form-control"%}
    {% comment %} <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search product" name="search-input" class="form-control rounded"> {% endcomment %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form></div>
{% block extra_js %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.my-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.my-form')[0].submit();
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>{% endblock extra_js %}
```

My view:

```
def search(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ProductNameForm(request.POST)
      place = ProductPlaceForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid() and place.is_valid():
          form.save()
          place.save()
          form = ProductNameForm()
          place = ProductPlaceForm()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/search_result')
  form = ProductNameForm()
  place = ProductPlaceForm()
  return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'form':form, 'place':place})
```

Comment: Django is server side, so no, there is no way to do this with only Django. Django has no hooks into browser events like that. You will have to add some JavaScript to the page to make that happen.

Comment: hi. i trying to add ajax to template but it not auto submit after timeout(2s). can you tell me what wrong. i already edit the question

Comment: i already done that but not thing show up if i console.log in timeout function

Comment: Your code fires on the form submit, prevents the submit from happening, waits 2 seconds, then fires the form submit. That seems pointless and not at all what you intended.